# Binding an ember model's date attribute to month/day/year select tags

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have an Ember model with a date attribute to store a user's birthday. I would like to bind the value of this attribute to three html select tags (one for month, day, and year), but I don't know how. Since the data is stored on the model as a timestamp, it's not as simple as binding an html element straight to a model property.

I'm using ember 1.12 and ember-cli. I've looked into [emberx-select](https://github.com/thefrontside/emberx-select) for constructing and binding to the actual select and option elements, but I'm not sure how to bind each select to a distinct piece of the date attribute.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can write a component for the job. The component's one property will be directly binded to the date/timestamp field. and inside component you can have a computed property with setter.

Comment: Could you spell this out a little more as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant directly connect to the model using the `DS.attr(date)`,but You can create a js date from three inputs, and then assign the date to the models attribute

Since ember is going the path of data down actions up, in my example i built a component that fires a dateChanged event everytime the inputs are updated with a valid date

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vuyoso/edit?html,js,output

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  date:new Date(2001,2,2),
  actions:{
    dateChanged:function(date){
      this.set('date',date);
    }
  }
});

App.DateInputComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  day:null,
  month:null,
  year:null,

  onDateChanged:function(){
      var date = new Date(this.get('year'), this.get('month'), this.get('day'));
      if(date !== 'Invalid Date'){
        this.sendAction('dateChanged',date);
      }
  }.observes('day','month','year')
});


  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/date-input">
   day:{{input value=day}}<\ br>
   month:{{input value=month}}<\ br>
   year:{{input value=year}}<\ br>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
     {{date-input dateChanged="dateChanged"}}
  {{date}}
  </script>
```

To go from date to day,month,year

Use ember computed to transform the date object

Model :

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
   date:DS.attr('date'),
   year:Ember.computed('date',function(){return this.get('date').getYear()}
   month:Ember.computed('date',function(){return this.get('date').getMonth()}
   day:Ember.computed('date',function(){return this.get('date').getDay()}
})
```

Or Component:

`{{my-component date=date}}`

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
   year:Ember.computed('date',function(){return this.get('date').getYear()}
   month:Ember.computed('date',function(){return this.get('date').getMonth()}
   day:Ember.computed('date',function(){return this.get('date').getDay()}
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't think this solution will update the model when the user interacts with the form inputs, does it?

Comment: if the the form updates the date property, then it will

Comment: Right, but the form consists of three select elements, (one for month, day, and year) so I don't know how they would all be directly bound to the date property.

Comment: does your model have date,year,month attributes or date attribute ?

Comment: It has a date attribute. I could change this to day/month/year and use a transform to maintain consistency with the api, but shouldn't I be using Ember's built in date data type instead of creating my own?